# Enabling mouse events in terminal for ncurses

Tags: c++, mouseevent, ncurses

Prior to making this post, I've had a look at several previous posts about this topic, but have had trouble understanding what the problem is and close to no luck getting it to work for WSL2.

So far, I've got it to work with ZSH on iTerm2 and VSCode on Mac, where using the line `printf("\033[?1003h)"` allows me to receive mouse clicking (except for right-click), scrolling (except for scrolling down) and movement events, where mouse movement is tracked throughout the whole screen.

For WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows Terminal, using the same print line allows me to receive mouse clicking, mouse scrolling, and movement events, however mouse movement tracking is restricted to 0 - 94 columns. For WSL2 Ubuntu on VSCode, I don't receive any events.

I would really appreciate any sort of help I could get.

Code I've been using to test this (not my code):

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();

  // Enables keypad mode. This makes (at least for me) mouse events getting
  // reported as KEY_MOUSE, instead as of random letters.
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

  // Don't mask any mouse events
  mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, NULL);

  // echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h"
  printf("\033[?1003h\n"); // Makes the terminal report mouse movement events

  for (;;) { 
    int c = wgetch(stdscr);
 
    // Exit the program on new line fed
    if (c == '\n')
      break;
 
    char buffer[512];
    size_t max_size = sizeof(buffer);
    if (c == ERR) {
      snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Nothing happened.");
    }
    else if (c == KEY_MOUSE) {
      MEVENT event;
      if (getmouse(&event) == OK) {
        snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Mouse at row=%d, column=%d bstate=0x%08lx",
                 event.y, event.x, event.bstate);
      }
      else {
        snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Got bad mouse event.");
      }
    }
    else {
      snprintf(buffer, max_size, "Pressed key %d (%s)", c, keyname(c));      
    }
 
    move(0, 0);
    insertln();
    addstr(buffer);
    clrtoeol();
    move(0, 0);
  }
 
  printf("\033[?1003l\n"); // Disable mouse movement events, as l = low

  endwin();
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example won't work because the printf isn't flushed.

Comment: Also, `printf` escape sequences aren't magically incorperated by `*curses` in its state machine. Use `*curses` all the way and you'll be fine. This: `printf("\033[?1003h\n"); // Makes the terminal report mouse movement events` may be true for _some_ terminals. When you use `*curses` you shouldn't care about the exact sequence. Use whatever is in the termcap library.

Comment: @ThomasDickey By flushing do you mean adding something like `fflush(stdout)` after the print line? Because I tried that and the results are the same.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by using `*curses` all the way.

Comment: @Locklan Don't send _any_ raw escape sequences. If you send `\033[?1003h` to a `VT52` terminal - it will not understand what you mean. Use the `*curses` functions to do what you want to do - all the time. Don't make any exceptions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm still struggling with this. Do I use functions such as `putp()` to send the line to the terminal? Or am I missing the point completely? I've had a look at <https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html> but have no idea what I'm looking.

Comment: @Locklan Yes, you sort of missed the point. You, as a programmer, should care little about the actual escape sequences (that makes terminals do stuff). Use only the functions the library provides.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Alright, thanks for the clarification